# SpringBootTest not picking up @Profile

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have a

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(classes=[AppConfigTest])
@AcitveProfile("unittest")
ControllerTest
```

in which

```
@TestConfiguration
@Profile("unittest")
AppConfigTest
```

and is located under `/src/test` package. AppConfigTest has beans to override the beans defined in AppConfig. The ControllerTest runs just fine, pick up the beans in AppConfigTest instead of AppConfig.

Now, I create

```
@Configuration
@Profile(["local", "unittest"])
AppConfigLocal
```

located under `/src/main`, and if I change ControllerTest to

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [AppConfigLocal])
@ActiveProfile("unittest")
ControllerTest
```

Now my ControllerTest doesn't seem to pick up the Controller anymore (tests failed with 'no mapping found for HTTP request with URI...'

But it doesn't really says why the Controller wasn't wired to the mockmvc...

Comment: working examples: https://github.com/dimoTicket/dimo-core/tree/dev/src/test/java

Answer (score 0):

The package that you're @Profile is must be the same as where your Application is.